# How do I make an element or div sticky using css?

Tags: html, css, sticky

I have this html code where it has a main content on the left and a side bar on the right. My goal is to have the last sidebar (the one with the "faq" class) stick to it's position whenever I scrolled down in the main content and when I scroll back up, it should return all the div class(about,contact,faq)to its position. I've tried using the 'position: sticky;' on the "faq" class but the problem is that it doesn't stick. What should I do?

This is the HTML&CSS code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Add a gray background color with some padding */

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}


/* Header/Blog Title */

.header {
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */


/* Left column */

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 90px;
}


/* Right column */

.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 90px;
}


/* Fake image */

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Add a card effect for articles */

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}


/* this is for the side bar, this is where I should implement the sticky feature*/

.about {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.contact {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.faq {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

  <title>Eat Blog-a</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Blog Name</h2>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <h5>Posted by (Username)</h5>
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <p>Content</p>

        <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px">Image</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h5>Posted by (Username)</h5>
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <p>Content</p>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px">Image</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">

      <div class="about">
        <p>This is where we will put the about area</p>

      </div>

      <div class="contact">
        <p>This is where we will put the about contact</p>
      </div>

      <div class="faq">
        <p>This is where we will put the about FAQ</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: div.fixed {
  position: fixed;
}

Comment: I've tried it and it sticks in a fixed position. What if instead I wanted the faq to stick at the top when scrolling down? how do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Sticky` only works when `the parent element` has height greater than `total height of children`, so I used `position: absolute; height: 100%` to set height for `the parent element`.

```
.row{
  position: relative;
}

.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
}

.faq{
  ...
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;  
 }
```

Comment: This is almost close, but I only want the faq to stick when scrolling down.

Comment: i have edited my answer for your request, let's try it @Imaginewagons

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to make your element sticky when you scroll by it using pure CSS, however you can do it with the following JavaScript function. I wrote this using jQuery and I think this is what you are looking for =>

```js
/* jQuery */
window.onscroll = function JQanchorOnScroll() {
  var $anchor = $(".faq-anchor");
  var $element = $('.faq');

  var move = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    var OffsetTop = $anchor.offset().top;
    if (scrollTop > OffsetTop) {
      $element.css({
        position: "fixed",
        top: "0px"
      });
    } else {
      $element.css({
        position: "relative",
        top: ""
      });
    }
  };
  $(window).scroll(move);
  move();
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}


/* Add a gray background color with some padding */

body {
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 20px;
  background: #f1f1f1;
  height: 5000px;
}


/* Header/Blog Title */

.header {
  padding: 30px;
  font-size: 40px;
  text-align: center;
}


/* Create two unequal columns that floats next to each other */


/* Left column */

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 90px;
}


/* Right column */

.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 90px;
}


/* Fake image */

.fakeimg {
  background-color: #aaa;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
}


/* Add a card effect for articles */

.card {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Clear floats after the columns */

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}


/* Footer */

.footer {
  padding: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  background: #ddd;
  margin-top: 20px;
}


/* Responsive layout - when the screen is less than 800px wide, make the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */

@media screen and (max-width: 800px) {
  .leftcolumn,
  .rightcolumn {
    width: 100%;
    padding: 0;
  }
}


/* this is for the side bar, this is where I should implement the sticky feature*/

.about {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.contact {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.faq {
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />

  <title>Eat Blog-a</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Blog Name</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
      <div class="card">
        <h5>Posted by (Username)</h5>
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <p>Content</p>

        <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px">Image</div>
      </div>
      <div class="card">
        <h5>Posted by (Username)</h5>
        <h2>Description</h2>
        <p>Content</p>
        <div class="fakeimg" style="height: 200px">Image</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">

      <div class="about">
        <p>This is where we will put the about area</p>

      </div>

      <div class="contact">
        <p>This is where we will put the about contact</p>
      </div>
      <div class="faq-anchor"></div>
      <div class="faq">
        <p>This is where we will put the about FAQ</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I hope this helped, if this isn't what you are looking for let me know, and I will look further into it.

Comment: Sorry but, I am still a beginner at this and unfortunately I still have a hard time understanding jQuery.  but this will be good material to come back to when I start learning JQuery

Comment: When you add position sticky to element, the stickiness on that element gets active when its there to get sticky. so onscroll of some element sticky can be achieved.

Comment: @Imaginewagons this function simply adds the css attribute `position: fixed` when the `faq` element is closer to the top of the browser then the `faq-anchor` and removes it whenever the anchor is closer to top again so when you scroll back up the element is back in its original state.

Comment: I see, so that's how it works. I ran the snippet and this is exactly what I was looking for but unfortunately I have yet to get to JQuery in my Lessons. Once we get to JQuery I will definitely try this.

Comment: Do you have Pure JS skills? @Imaginewagons I can try to rewrite it to pure JS if that's more convenient for you

Comment: @FUZIION Right now I only know the very basics of JS, as well as some CSS, html, and bootstrap since I am still starting out. I have yet to tackle advance lessons

Answer (score -1):

Solution:
To make faq column sticky

```css
.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

/*to test it it's sticky
do this */

.leftcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 75%;
  padding-left: 90px;
  min-height: 200vh;
}
```

To make faq column fixed:

```css
.rightcolumn {
  float: left;
  width: 25%;
  height: 100%;
  padding-left: 20px;
  padding-right: 90px;
  position: fixed;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Not what OP requested

Comment: This is almost close! The problem is that it also sticks the about and content. I only want to stick the faq itself if it reaches the top of the page. not the whole column.

Comment: Then on a particular faq try doing this : `position:sticky,top:0`

Comment: @MohammedShahed This is the solution I tried but It doesn't work whenever I add it to the last div.  but whenever I add it to the other divs, for example the content div. It works.